# Landscape Openstack-installer fails during juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I've got my MAAS and behind my server I've got my 5 nodes all are ready to use (status ready in MAAS)

First I used MAAS and JUJU without Landscape and it works perfectly fine.
Juju bootstrap OK.
Use charm OK. I installed charm like mysql and wordpress.
After that I destroyed my bootstrap environment to use the autopilot.

I used this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable

sudo apt install openstack

sudo openstack-install
```

I launched all these commands on my Maas server.

But I've got this an error "Problem with JuJu bootstrap"

Here is my ~/.cloud-install/commands.log

```
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:19:46] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
   Num items: 2, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:19:56] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:20:48] • cloudinstall.ui • (__init__.py, submit, 214)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('Landscape OpenStack Autopilot', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Landscape OpenStack Autopilot' state=True>, 'Benefit from best practices in c$
[INFO  • 06-01 18:20:48] • cloudinstall.install • (install.py, do_install, 129)]
   Performing a Landscape OpenStack Autopilot install
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:20:48] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
   Num items: 4, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:23:07] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('admin_email', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('admin_name', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_server', <EditInput selectable flow w$
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:23:07] • cloudinstall.landscape_install • (landscape_install.py, _save_lds_creds, 81)]
   Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:24:23] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, ssh_genkey, 819)]
   ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:24:23] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 137)]
   Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/tibo/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:32:54] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 143)]
   Problem during bootstrap: '{'status': 1, 'output': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nBootstrap failed, destroying environment\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: Juju cann$
[DEBUG • 06-01 18:32:54] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

I don't know what is my problem.

Comment: the error response output was cut short, can you paste.ubuntu.com the full commands.log?

Comment: The Error response was that :
Problem during bootstrap: '{'status': 1, 'output': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nBootstrap failed, destroying environment\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: Juju cannot bootstrap because no tools are available for your environment.\nYou may want to use the \'agent-metadata-url\' configuration setting to specify the tools location.\n\n'}'

What does it mean ?

Comment: That's an odd error to have at this state. When you did your bootstrap and deploy tests, was it from the same machine? What version of juju do you have there? dpkg-query -W juju-core

Comment: @andreas
When I did my test it was on my maas server. I destroyed my bootstrap environment to use Landscape autopilot.
 I use juju-core  "1.23.3-0ubuntu1~14.04.1~juju1

Comment: @gangstaluv any ideas ?

Comment: Try to bootstrap on MAAS with --debug, see if that gives any more clues.

Comment: Or add an additional switch and try to bootstrap outside of the installer with , `juju bootstrap --upload-tools --debug`

Comment: @andreas When I juju bootstrap it works perfectly well ! But I was stuck after that to deploy charm because juju didn't use my upstream DNS. If I want to deploy Charm I need to add my "nameserver" into "etc/resolv.conf" on my bootstrap node...
I think my problem is there for Landscape. How to fix that ? or how juju or Landscape can use this upstream DNS ??

Comment: @gangstaluv see my comment.

Comment: The nodes will use the MAAS server as their DNS. You may need to point MAAS to an upstream DNS server, there is a config for that in the MAAS settings page.

Comment: @andreas I already did that !! I add an upstream DNS !! but my nodes don't use it

Comment: Right, the nodes will use the MAAS IP as DNS, and MAAS itself will use upstream for domains that does not fall under its responsibility.